# Can we add Possible Duplicates even after a question is closed?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I think it would help to make sure that the possible duplicates link to all older duplicate questions, even if everyone who voted to close picked the same one or two questions. However, I'm not sure how it would look and act, rep requirements, and more, so I figure I'll throw the idea out there and let the rest of the SO community help come up with something cool.

Answer (score 2):

Well those with sufficient rep can still edit questions after they've been closed to add the links manually.

Is that what you mean or have I missed the point of your question completely?

Comment: I meant adding them to the box that's added when the question is closed as a duplicate. It seems they would get more visibility there.

Comment: Isn't that just formatted text in the body of the question?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1063196/edit (assuming you've got edit rights over on SO)

Answer (score 0):

Editing the question to add in the duplicates is much more efficient. If the question is already closed, you won't see the box with the duplicate possibilities anyway because you won't be able to vote for it to close (since it's already closed).

Comment: that's why the duplicate box should have a field to add a new question (and perhaps even remove an old question) to the box, with a limit of 5 possible duplicates.